# reaarange array after deleting its element

Tags: php

hi 
i have array like $arr with 10 elements when i unset the 5 element  and print the array it print he array without 5 indx. now i want to rearrange the array with 9 elements and first four values index will be same but after this values should be shifted to (previous index-1).
is there any simple method is there (array function). or i have to made a complete logic for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, if you want to maintain order, but just want to re-index the keys, you can use the [`array_values()`](https://www.php.net/array_values) function.

```
$a = array(
    0 => 'a', 
    1 => 'b',
    2 => 'c', 
    3 => 'd'
);
unset($a[1]);
$a = array(
    0 => 'a', 
    2 => 'c', 
    3 => 'd'
); // Note, this is what $a is now, the re-assignment is for illustration only
$a = array_values($a);
$a = array(
    0 => 'a', 
    1 => 'c', 
    2 => 'd'
); // Note, this is what $a is now, the re-assignment is for illustration only
```

Comment: Nice one, never thought of that.

Comment: +1, I agree this might be more appropriate in certain situations.

Answer (score 3):

You should use [`array_splice`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php), rather than `unset`, to remove the elements from the array.  Doing so will reorder the remaining elements:

```
$input = array("red", "green", "blue", "yellow");
array_splice($input, 1, 1);
// $input is now array("red", "blue", "yellow")
```

Comment: This is assuming that you know all the keys at the same time, and that they are all sequential.  if that's the case, this works fine and is indeed more efficient.  However if either of the two conditions is not true, then multiple `unset` calls fallowed by an `array_values()` call will likely be more efficient (and have more semantic meaning)...  Otherwise +1...

Answer (score 0):

Not too sure if there's a better way but you can use [array_reverse()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reverse.php), twice:

```
$array = array_reverse($array, false);
$array = array_reverse($array, false);
```